# Apache mod_rewrite showing no effect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using WAMP, the latest version with Apache 2.4.9. I was trying to beautify my URLs using mod_rewrite, that's preinstalled in my system. I uncommented the # before this line in httpd.conf:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

became

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

restarted the server, and wrote the following re-write rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^localhost/testmod/(\W+).php$ localhost/testmod/$1
```

I saved it in a directory named testmode. Without modifications, URL of a file named test.php inside this folder looks like: localhost/testmode/test.php and I want to strip out the .php from the URL.

It doesn't change anything. The URL is same, localhost/testmode/test.php.
Am I making any mistake in the regexp or something else is wrong?

Comment: So you have a _folder_ named `localhost` in your web root? (If not, and this is actually the host name: `RewriteRule` matches on the _path_ component of the request only.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `.htaccess` inside `testmod` folder then these rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testmod/

## To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn that around:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testmod/(\W+)$ testmod/$1.php [L]
```

Think of it like that: the *incoming* request is to `http://localhost/testmod/test`, *that* string has to be matched by the regex pattern. Then you internally map that the the physical script `http://localhost/testmod/test.php` in your file system.

Also make sure that the interpretation of such `.htaccess` style files is enabled in your http server.

And two general notes:

1. Since it is your system I assume you have control over the configuration of the http server. If so it *always* is better to place such rewriting rules (and similar stuff) in there instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and *really* slow the server down. They are only meant as a last fallback for those who do *not* have access to the configuration of the http server.

   Note that you need a slight modification of the rule syntax if you decide to place the rules in the real server configuration:

   `RewriteRule ^/testmod/(\W+)$ /testmod/$1.php [L]`
2. Your question is answered in the documentation of the apache module you want to use. You really should read that documentation. It is precise, complete and offers really good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: And where to check if such interpretations are allowed?

Comment: As said above: check the documentation! That is what it is there for.  It will point you to a `AllowOverride` command which has to be placed in the http server configuration.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just realized another issue with your rules, so I changed the syntax above once more. Sorry for that.